# Unable to expose SCTP server running in a kubernetes pod using NodePort

Tags: linux, kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, sctp, 5g

I have a single node kubernetes cluster running in a VM in azure. I have a service running SCTP server in port 38412. I need to expose that port externally. I have tried by changing the port type to NodePort. But no success. I am using flannel as a overlay network. using Kubernetes version 1.23.3.

This is my service.yaml file

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    meta.helm.sh/release-name: fivegcore
    meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: open5gs
  creationTimestamp: "2022-02-11T09:24:09Z"
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    epc-mode: amf
  name: fivegcore-amf
  namespace: open5gs
  resourceVersion: "33072"
  uid: 4392dd8d-2561-49ab-9d57-47426b5d951b
spec:
  clusterIP: 10.111.94.85
  clusterIPs:
  - 10.111.94.85
  externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  internalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  ipFamilies:
  - IPv4
  ipFamilyPolicy: SingleStack
  ports:
  - name: tcp
    nodePort: 30314
    port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 80
  - name: ngap
    nodePort: 30090
    port: 38412
    protocol: SCTP
    targetPort: 38412
  selector:
    epc-mode: amf
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: NodePort
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

As you can see I changed the port type to NodePort.

```
open5gs fivegcore-amf NodePort 10.111.94.85  <none>  80:30314/TCP,38412:30090/SCTP
```

This is my Configmap.yaml. In this configmap that ngap dev is the server I want to connect which is using default eth0 interface in the container.

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  amf.yaml: |
    logger:
        file: /var/log/open5gs/amf.log
        #level: debug
        #domain: sbi

    amf:
        sbi:
        - addr: 0.0.0.0
          advertise: fivegcore-amf
        ngap:
          dev: eth0
        guami:
          - plmn_id:
              mcc: 208
              mnc: 93
            amf_id:
              region: 2
              set: 1
        tai:
          - plmn_id:
              mcc: 208
              mnc: 93
            tac: 7
        plmn_support:
        - plmn_id:
            mcc: 208
            mnc: 93
          s_nssai:
          - sst: 1
            sd: 1
        security:
            integrity_order : [ NIA2, NIA1, NIA0 ]
            ciphering_order : [ NEA0, NEA1, NEA2 ]
        network_name:
            full: Open5GS
        amf_name: open5gs-amf0
    nrf:
     sbi:
       name: fivegcore-nrf
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  annotations:
    meta.helm.sh/release-name: fivegcore
    meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: open5gs
  creationTimestamp: "2022-02-11T09:24:09Z"
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    epc-mode: amf
```

I exec in to the container and check whether the server is running or not.
This is the netstat of the container.

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 10.244.0.31:37742       10.105.167.186:80       ESTABLISHED 1/open5gs-amfd
sctp                10.244.0.31:38412                               LISTEN      1/open5gs-amfd
```

sctp module is also loaded in the host.

```
$lsmod | grep sctp
sctp                  356352  8
xt_sctp                20480  0
libcrc32c              16384  5 nf_conntrack,nf_nat,nf_tables,ip_vs,sctp
x_tables               49152  18 ip6table_filter,xt_conntrack,xt_statistic,iptable_filter,iptable_security,xt_tcpudp,xt_addrtype,xt_nat,xt_comment,xt_owner,ip6_tables,xt_sctp,ipt_REJECT,ip_tables,ip6table_mangle,xt_MASQUERADE,iptable_mangle,xt_mark
```

Is it possible to expose this server externally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither AKS nor Flannel supports SCTP at this point of writing. Here's some [details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/573521/does-azure-aks-support-sctp-and-how-to-enable-it.html) about it.

Comment: I also tried it with calico. It is also not working. Am I missing something?

Comment: The host needs to have `sctp` loaded.

Comment: It is loaded. I added that to the question now.

Comment: Your original question is using `sctp` on Azure AKS with Flannel. You need to mark the answer and start a new question with new scenario/setup. Switching question like this will cause confusion to the next person who read the posts.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot expose port 38412 externally because the default node port range in Kubernetes is 30000-32767.

The best solution (which I tried and working) is to deploy a router/firewall in between Kubernetes cluster and the external srsRAN. On firewall map SCTP port 38412 --> 31412.

Initiate the connection from srsRAN/UERANSIM and the firewall will do the magic and make your RAN connect to the 5g CORE.

PS: I deployed this solution on OpenStack.

Answer (score 1):

We found that using a nodeport to translate ports breaks the SCTP protocol (see rfc 4960) because the SCTP transport address structure (embedded in each stream) will match the nodeport port, not the sctp port. Using a port translation (e.g. nodeport or firewall) will therefore cause the decryptor to fail in the 5g core NF's we have worked with. This is obviously not a problem if the code listens on the same port as the nodeport. Port 38412 is only recommended, it is not required. Can you recompile your code to use a port in the nodeport range? Or turn off the decryptor error function?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please phrase this as an explained conditional answer, in order to avoid the impression of asking a clarification question instead of answering (for which [a comment should be used instead of an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173)). For example like "If your problem is ... then the solution is to .... because .... ."